# How to fetch the data date wise from netCDF or .grd file in CDO software?

Tags: interpolation, netcdf, temperature, cdo-climate, grads

I have data files of min/max temperature in .grd or netCDF format. From these files, I want to fetch the data date wise for India lat/long points only using CDO or grADS software.
The data format is:

| lat | lon | tmax |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 77 | 26.43 |
| 8 | 78 | 26.47 |

and I want in:

| lat | lon | ind_lat_lon | obs_date | tmax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 77 | 1 | 02-01-2021 | 26.43 |
| 8 | 78 | 1 | 02-01-2021 | 26.47 |

this format using CDO/grADS.

Comment: There are numerous options available in CDO, as the user guide shows: https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/embedded/cdo.pdf. What have you tried doing?

Comment: Can you suggest to me what option I should try..? Actually, I haven't tried any option because I am new to CDO.

Comment: Please search through the user guide. It should not be dificult to find a suitable method

Comment: I have tried 'seldate' function in CDO but I am not getting the date column while converting the netCDF file into .csv format. The output I am getting is lat, lon, time, tmax. In time column timestamp data I am getting for e.g. "17455848.0" but I want dates in place of "17455848.0".

Comment: hi CDO doesn't convert into csv... CDO will allow to extract a region to another netcdf or GRIB file... then to dump the file information you can use ncdump to view the header and contents as a CDL file.  If instead you want to convert to a full csv file (there is NEVER a good reason to want to do that though!) you can use R or python... but as I say, there is not a single reason why you would want to have gridded information in a CSV format, netcdf is so much easier and safer to work with directly

Answer (score 1):

I think the slicing functions you need in space is

```
 cdo sellonlatbox,lon1,lon2,lat1,lat2 in.nc out.nc
```

to select a region around india,

and

```
 cdo seldate,yyyymmdd1,yymmdd2 in.nc out.nc
```

to select the date range.